# Getting Error of "Connection Timed Out" and "OS Error"

Tags: postgresql, flutter, dart

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Gorgeo 4GL in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
V/PhoneWindow(10971): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = ViewRoot{4b712b0 com.example.thesocial/com.example.thesocial.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this = DecorView@b80e062[MainActivity]
D/Surface (10971): Surface::connect(this=0x8b962000,api=1)
D/Surface (10971): Surface::connect(this=0x8b8fd000,api=1)
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:52475/qaS-Qs8zk5w=/ws
I/zygote  (10971): Do partial code cache collection, code=18KB, data=30KB
I/zygote  (10971): After code cache collection, code=18KB, data=30KB
I/zygote  (10971): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/zygote  (10971): Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=61KB
I/zygote  (10971): After code cache collection, code=61KB, data=61KB
I/zygote  (10971): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I/flutter (10971): http://10.0.2.2:8000/user/signup
I/flutter (10971): SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 56162
```

> Getting this Error:
> I/flutter (10971): SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 56162

Comment: Please check your network connection or on your real device or emulator wifi or internet is on if its ok **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />**
add this line to the **android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml** file

Comment: In which tag should I add this line?

Comment: Add **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />** this line inside <manifest> tag above the start of <application> tag or see my answer

Comment: It's giving the same error again.

Comment: Is it the mistake in the  URL (http://10.0.2.2:8000) ?? I mean should I use my network address ??

Comment: can you share your network url ?

Comment: This is my network URL -  http://192.168.29.169

Comment: I think you can create temporary URL using **ngrok** it create the your network URL to http or https url

Comment: I don't no what it is. I am a complete beginner. Can you explain it more.

Comment: And one more thing I am using a physical device for testing.

Comment: **ngrok** is public URL testing tool . **ngrok allows you to expose a web server running on your local machine to the internet. Just tell ngrok what port your web server is listening on.**  https://ngrok.com/download this is download tool for ngrok when you download it type **ngrok http 80** replace 80 by your port number and you get url add this url to your code and test it. ngrok reference https://ngrok.com/docs

Comment: Welcome @ Anoop

Comment: I cannot upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation. But I will Accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Ok Anoop No problem thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shop_app">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application>
```