# I get “OS Error: Connection Refused , errno=111, port = 59374” in flutter when using 'NetworkImage'

Tags: flutter

I am a new beginner in Flutter,:),  I'm using Image widget but have OS error

This is my Flutter code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
        body: Image(image: NetworkImage('https://www.w3schools.com/w3css//img_lights.jpg'),),
     )));
}
```

[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ueLD.png)
Whenever I run the code their is a error named Connection Refused

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code, I think you don't add the internet permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** file
Add this code inside **manifest tag** or below **manifest tag**

Or see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444642/13997210)

Go to -> /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```