# Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 51158 in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, rest, socketexception

I'm building a flutter app. The api is working fine in Postman but in flutter app it is showing the above error. The request is been sent on http address.

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68546991/13997210) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444642/13997210) answer hope it helps to you

Answer (score 0):

Find out the location of adb.exe, then run the command, something like,

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb reverse tcp:51158 tcp:51158"
```