# Why is my api failing with a "SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused" in flutter but not on web or postman?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I'm calling a login api I can get it working in postman, on my browser and in native android code, however when I call the same api in flutter,   I get the following error:

`DioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 10.0.0.25, port = 53330 #0`

I know the api url is correct, the body is correct(it's a post) and the headers/cookies are correct as I set it up in postman and it works with all the same info just mentioned.

Here is the call to the API

```
    api.login(deviceId, requestObj).then((response) {
        _processLogin(response);
        _sofiPrefs!.saveEmail(email!);
        if (Foundation.kDebugMode) {
      _sofiPrefs!.saveDebugPassword(password);
        }
      }).catchError((error) {
        _loginError(error);
      });
```

And the api set up for DIO: (url has been changed)

```
part 'network_services.g.dart';

@RestApi()
abstract class NetworkServices {
  factory NetworkServices() {
    return _NetworkServices(serviceLocator<Dio>());
  }

  @POST("login/mobile/login")
  Future<HttpResponse<LoginResponsev3>> login(
      @Header(dIDHeader) String dId, @Body() LoginReq request);
}
```

And the response model

```
@JsonSerializable()
class LoginResponsev3 {
  String? email;
  String? twoFactorType;
  String? twoFactorData;
  String? twoFactorSessionToken; 

  LoginResponse(
      this.email,
      this.twoFactorType,
      this.twoFactorData,
      this.twoFactorSessionToken);

  factory LoginResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$LoginResponseFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LoginResponseToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: vpn or proxy on the target device?

Comment: try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68546991/13997210) hope its helpful to you.

Comment: Did you check that the API is up and running first? Use `curl` or Postman. `Connection refused` usually means that there is no API running or URL is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if hava the internet permission on the android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And also add usesCleartextTraffic

```
 <manifest ...>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
    ...
</application>
```

More important, this is an Mobile/Web/Desktop application?