# Solutions not working - Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform

Tags: python, flutter, http, flask, rest

I am trying to write an application using flutter as frontend with python as backend. I am creating a rest api with python and now trying to send requests to it with flutter.

I am getting the following error when running the attached code in flutter:
SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127 .0.0.1, port = 43360

I tried switching the localhost with the address of IPv4 and got the error:
Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http: //IPv4_adress:5000/product/1.

I tried all the solutions I found online, like adding to myapp\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
```

I also tried to change the HTTP to HTTPS but I am only getting the error:
SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.100.102.15, port = 59658

I reloaded the app but the errors remain.

I used the guide in this link https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data and it worked fine. The errors occurred after I changed the album class to the product class and the url to my rest api url.
I created the rest api using python with flask and sqlalchemy and I am able to send requests to it with postman and chrome.

Flutter code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Product> fetchProduct() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/product/1'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load Product');
  }
}

class Product {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final int qty;

  Product({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.qty,
  });

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      description: json['description'],
      price: json['price'],
      qty: json['qty'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<Product> futureProdcut;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureProdcut = fetchProduct();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Product>(
            future: futureProdcut,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.name);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                print(snapshot.error);
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

# init app
app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
#database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'db.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
# Init db
db =SQLAlchemy(app)
# Init ma
ma = Marshmallow(app)

#Product Class/model
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200))
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    qty = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, name, description, price, qty):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.price = price
        self.qty = qty

# Product Schema
class ProductSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'qty')

# Init Schema
product_schema = ProductSchema()
products_schema = ProductSchema(many=True)

# Create a Product
@app.route('/product', methods=['POST'])
def add_product():
    name = request.json['name']
    description = request.json['description']
    price = request.json['price']
    qty = request.json['qty']

    new_product = Product(name, description, price, qty)

    db.session.add(new_product)
    db.session.commit()

    return product_schema.jsonify(new_product)

# Get All Products
@app.route('/product', methods=['GET'])
def get_prodcuts():
    all_products = Product.query.all()
    result = products_schema.dump(all_products)
    print(result)
    print(type(result))
    return jsonify(result)

# Get Single Products
@app.route('/product/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_prodcut(id):
    product = Product.query.get(id)
    return product_schema.jsonify(product)

# Update a Product
@app.route('/product/<id>', methods=['PUT'])
def update_product(id):
    product = Product.query.get(id)
    name = request.json['name']
    description = request.json['description']
    price = request.json['price']
    qty = request.json['qty']

    product.name = name
    product.description = description
    product.price = price
    product.qty = qty

    db.session.commit()

    return product_schema.jsonify(product)

# run server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't do what the folks building the tools and infrastructure _intended_ you to do, and start using HTTPS?

Comment: We followed the guide where it was instructed to use http.
We tried to change http to https but we got the error:
SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.100.102.15, port = 59658

Comment: Which guide? Where?

Comment: like I wrote in the post: <https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data>

Comment: (regardless, a guide telling you to use HTTP for communications from an Android or iOS app is out-of-date and wrong; this is disabled by default for very good reasons).

Comment: Add internet permission to AndroidMenifest.xml file see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444642/13997210

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data is telling you to use the HTTP _package_, not the HTTP _protocol_ (on its own).

Comment: do you have another recommendation? I am trying to learn.

Comment: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https is one of the first links from Google from searching "flask TLS". It looks reasonable as a starting point.

Comment: ...more advanced configurations typically put a web server like nginx, apache httpd, traefik, etc. in front and have those do the SSL termination, speaking HTTPS to the client and then HTTP to the application server. (In some languages, particularly Go, the native SSL/TLS server implementations are good enough to be used in production on their own; but that's not typically the case with Python).

Comment: (eventually when you go to real-world production you might think about techniques like certificate pinning, making your mobile application trust a SSL CA you generated yourself instead of using public-key infrastructure, to protect your customers against having their traffic sniffed by employers/governments/etc installing their own certificate authorities; but that's something for later, and hopefully you'll have security staff on hand when you get there).

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I already added this permission, I get the same error.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I will look at it, but I still don't really understand what to do to resolve the problem.

Comment: ...I don't know that I can put it any plainer than I already have. Change the URL from `http://...` to `https://...` on the client side, and update the server side to start serving HTTPS instead of plain HTTP, as described in the blog post ahead and numerous other resources.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I updated the server side and now it serves HTTPS, and I changed the URL on the client side to HTTPS, but I still get the error: SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.100.102.15, port = 59674
I also restarted the app.

Comment: "Connection timed out" means what it says. I'd be start by ruling out networking bugs -- if you use a tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to watch the network traffic reaching your server, you should be able to determine whether the packets are getting there at all. If they aren't, make sure your Android device is connected to the same wifi network, make sure it _doesn't_ have any data connection that traffic could be going over to bypass wifi, sniff the network traffic at the router / access point, etc.