# Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 56782 python

Tags: python, flutter, api, dart, flask

I was trying to link the flutter app with python with API. My python code generated http://127.0.0.1:5000/ URL. When I used this in flutter code it threw the error

Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 56782

I found a solution in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0RVbqvdY2w)

Why does this solution work??

Comment: You should try to add Internet permission in  AndroidMenifest.xml file refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444642/13997210)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `127.0.0.1` in your emulator, **it will refer to the android emulator not you pc.** 
And because there is no server running on android localhost at port 56782, it will create *connection refused error*.

In order to target you pc machine, where this emulator is running, you should be using `10.0.2.2`. If you are using websocket and server is running on your pc, you can use `ws://10.0.2.2` as socket url.