# OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7 on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am working on an app with Flutter and I get the following message constantly, the funny thing is that it works for 2 hours and then it starts giving these errors, I already have the connection permissions in Manifiest.xml I have also verified the URL everything is fine, my connection Internet is fine, everything works without problem, I already followed all the steps found on the internet but everyone talks about Manifiest and internet connection but everything is fine, it only happens at certain times.

Any ideas?

Message:

```
Exception has occurred.
```

SocketException (SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'mydomain.app' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7))

My Code:

```
static Future<List> getNews(userAuth) async {
final response = await http.post(Uri.https(url,"/rest/index.php/api/getNews"), body: {
  "authenticate":userAuth,
});    
return json.decode(response.body);
```

}

Comment: You should add Internet permission to AndroidManifest.xml file refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444642/13997210)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but as I already mentioned in my question, I already did that step and I have not been successful.

Comment: Same here, adding "android.permission.INTERNET" (was already in code), does not rid the issue.  But that's only in VS Code.  Things working without error in same emulator using Android Studio.  Why?