# Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'imap.gmail.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

Tags: flutter, imap

I was used imap_client package in my app to read my mail.
below is my connection code:

```
`ImapClient client = new ImapClient();
    await client.connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);
    print("success");`
```

Comment: Are you in germany?  Otherwise, you have underlying DNS issues.  In some countries, you need to use imap.googlemail.com.

Comment: Try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444642/13997210)  you should add Internet permission inside AndroidMenifest.xml file

Comment: The gamil.com issue in genannt was resolved many years ago. Money changed hands, as I recall.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your are not connected to internet. Or maybe the server you are using is temporarily down. Mainly there are the causes behind Socket Exception.