# Not able to resolve SocketException in flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, api

I'm trying to sign in users in my flutter app using an api that I have developed using node.js! My backend works perfectly and I have done all the tests with postman. But everytime I try to login in my frontend (which is flutter), I get the following error:

SocketException (SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = 192.168.56.1, port = 48550)

I have tried the following:

- Use of localhost/current ip in the base url of my api
- Check internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml
- Check that I have a good internet connection

Here is my code for the userController.js:

```
const privateKey = "this is a private key dsfdsgfqdsmlkfsdmqlf,kqdmsjdsmjfm"

exports.login=(email, password)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        db.User.findOne({where: {email:email}}).then(user=>{
            if (!user){
                reject('Invalid email and password')
            }
            {
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(same=>{
                    if(same){
                        let token = jwt.sign({id: user.id, username: user.username, role:user.role}, privateKey,
                        {expiresIn:"24h"})
                        let userRole = user.role
                        var map = {}
                        map.token = token
                        map.userRole = userRole
                        resolve(map)
                        //resolve({ token: { token }, user: { id: user.id, role: user.role } })

                    }
                    else{
                        reject('Invalid email and password')
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

and my login_screen.dart:

```
  Future<void> login() async {
    if (emailController.text.isNotEmpty && passwordController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse('http://192.168.56.1:3000/loginuser'),
          body: ({
            'email': emailController.text,
            'password': passwordController.text
          }));
      final Map body = jsonDecode(response.body);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('test');
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DoctorScreen()));
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Invalid user credentials')));
      }
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Please enter your credentials')));
    }
  }
```

I have been really stuck in here so I would appreciate it if anyone helps me out with it!

Comment: Is port number is correct ?

Comment: try to add internet permission to your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file-> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444642/13997210) for that hope its help to you.

Comment: `192.168.56.1` looks like a router address, not a host address.

Comment: Port number is correct, I've also used the internet permission correctly! concerning the adress that's my current ipv4 cus I've seen elsewhere that I should use it instead of localhost:3000 in order to fix this issue!